# How to set GENERATE_SOURCEMAP false in vite

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vite

Hi I deploy my react using vite, however all the source code showing from debugger. I want to hide it and already follow the step:

1. add `"build": "GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false vite build",`
2. using cross-env
3. and the last is try to set in vite config:

```
build: {
      outDir: 'build',
      chunkSizeWarningLimit: 1600,
      assetsDir: './',
      rollupOptions: {
        input: './src/index.jsx'
      },
      sourcemap: 'false'
    },
    sourcemap: {
      server: true,
      client: true,
    },
```

But all options not working.

Please see this image [image]

I want source code not showing on debugger.

Comment: finally I change my vite.config.js. I create new vite react project and copy all my code into new project, because before I use CRA and migrate into VITE. Also using `build serve` on DO command. Now all run well, debugger not showing sourcemap.

Answer (score 1):

You have to disable source maps. Here's how you can do :

1. In your package.json, update the build script to include GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false, like this :

```
"scripts": {
  "build": "GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false vite build"
}
```

2. Then you have to install the cross-env package :

```
npm install --save-dev cross-env
```

3. THen use cross-env to set the environment variable in the build script :

```
"scripts": {
  "build": "cross-env GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false vite build"
}
```

4. Finally, in your vite.config.js set the sourcemap option to false :

```
module.exports = {
  build: {
    sourcemap: false
  }
}
```

*Don't forget to restart your server*

Comment: As I describe above, I already do all 3 step but still no luck. I use app service on Digitalocean so I don't need to restart, because it auto rebuild and deploy.

Comment: Have you cleared your browser cache after deploying the updated build ?

Comment: yes, after your comment, I clear my browser cache, it still showing.

Comment: Ok so you can try to add the 'sourcemapExcludeSources' option to your vite.config.js file and set it to true

Comment: can you give me example how to put this code on vite? should I put this code inside build?

Comment: Like that :

```
module.exports = {
  build: {
    sourcemap: false,
    sourcemapExcludeSources: true
  }
}
```